# jsp learning its external URL behind a proxy

Tags: jsp

Consider a JSP page with the following things in it, sitting behind a reverse proxy.

The former could be addressed by the use of mod_proxy_html to rewrite the `link`, but it won't go spelunking in script elements. Is there some better solution than to pass the right URL in via -D and have that override pageContext.request.contextPath?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/services/legendcss/legend.css?version=2"
    type="text/css"/>


 <script>
    var bt_wd40_appurl = "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/services";
</script>
```

To clarify, perhaps:

Consider a copy of Tomcat reachable at `http://internalhost.com`, and a copy of Apache2 reachable on the public internet at `http://externalhost.com`.

The configuration for the Apache instance includes a reverse proxy that maps from `http://externalhost.com/blue/green/` to `http://internalhost.com/yellow`.

Now, the thing sitting at 'yellow' is a webapp, composed of web pages with javascript that need to talk to web services also inside the yellow webapp. We do not want to bake a pathname into these things. The code above will deliver 'internalhost' URLs to the browser, which cannot talk to them. I need it to deliver 'externalhost' URLS.

I prefer not to have code in JSP or HTML that makes assumptions about the URL it is deployed it, let alone the existence of a proxy.

Comment: Is it that your proxy is serving the pages under a different context than your deployment? Just trying to understand the question a bit better.

Comment: For reasons of security &cetra, there's a copy of apache2 over here, pointing to a copy of tomcat over there, with 'pointing' meaning 'has a reverse proxy configured'. So page.request... is 'over there', but the browser has to be told to talk to 'over here'.

Comment: I don't see the problem then... if the context is the same then why are you needing to rewrite the context path? Just use a `<c:url value="/servletpath" />` tag and ignore context completely. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Upon consideration, relative URLs for the web services seem to be the least bad alternative. Thus, the EL expression disappears altogether, and the URLs work just as well on either side of the proxy. This requires a constant path relationship between the JSP page and the web services, but that's a small price to pay.